# Somar date com int

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou tentando fazer uma soma de dias, informados em um campo `int`,com um campo `date` usando SQL. Testei da forma abaixo, mas ele soma o dia, mas ignora mês e ano. Existe alguma forma de fazer essa soma?

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(ocorrencias.dt_fechamento, '%d-%m-%Y')+50 as calendario from ocorrencias
```

Comment: Segue um tutorial que talvez possa te ajudar! link [http://www.devmedia.com.br/funcoes-de-manipulacao-de-data-do-mysql-5-5/25539](http://www.devmedia.com.br/funcoes-de-manipulacao-de-data-do-mysql-5-5/25539)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tenta utilizar o comando `DATE_ADD(ocorrencias.dt_fechamento, INTERVAL 50 DAY)`

**Exemplo:** `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(expiry_date,INTERVAL 3 DAY), '%d %m %Y' )`

Comment: Valeu! Era isso ai!

Answer (score 3):

Use a função `date_add()` do MySQL

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_add(ocorrencias.dt_fechamento, INTERVAL 50 day), '%d-%m-%Y') 
       as calendario FROM ocorrencias
```

Exemplo simples:

```
SELECT  date_add(now(), INTERVAL 50 day)
```

Comment: boa! vou anotar no caderno essa. Valeu!

Comment: @Diego isso mesmo, aproveite e anote a função que faz subtração em datas, `date_sub()` :D